# Error 403 using Google Drive API with Python - Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I'm getting the error 403 using the Google Drive API with Python.
I can see the files on google drive but when I tryed to download it I got the following error:

```
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"

  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
```

I'm using the code:

```
try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Drive API Quickstart'

def get_credentials():
    home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
    credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
    if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
        os.makedirs(credential_dir)
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                                   'drive-python-quickstart.json')

    store = Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        if flags:
            credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
        else: # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
            credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
        print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
    return credentials

def main():
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=http)

    results = service.files().list(
        q="'0BxZjsrGFMvPSNmprUFp0Y25BNFU' in parents", #first execution...
        pageSize=10,
        fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
    items = results.get('files', [])
    if not items:
        print('No files found.')
    else:
        print('Files:')
        for item in items:
            #print('{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))
            #file_id = '0BxZjsrGFMvPSWmtDYXB6RG5VTHM'
            request = service.files().get_media(fileId='0BxZjsrGFMvPSWmtDYXB6RG5VTHM')
            fh = io.BytesIO()
            downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
            done = False
            while done is False:
                status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
                #print ("Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I'm also have the OAuth 2.0 client configured: https://prnt.sc/gqasjz
I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
   "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"

  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
```

Means that you are trying to access a Google API without being authenticated first.  The credentials are not being properly applied to your service.   It should be popping up and asking you permission to access your data.